# Does Hash override Enumerable#map()?

Tags: ruby, enumerable

Given that `map()` is defined by `Enumerable`, how can `Hash#map` `yield` two variables to its block?  Does `Hash` override `Enumerable#map()`?

Here's a little example, for fun:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > {"herp" => "derp"}.map{|k,v| k+v}
 => ["herpderp"]
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It doesn't override map

```
Hash.new.method(:map).owner # => Enumerable
```

It yields two variables which get collected into an array

```
class Nums
  include Enumerable

  def each
    yield 1
    yield 1, 2
    yield 3, 4, 5
  end
end

Nums.new.to_a # => [1, [1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]
```

Comment: Ah, of course `Hash` must define `each` in order to mix in `Enumerable`.  What a great design!

Comment: Nice reflection with method() and owner() btw.  I'll have to remember that.

Answer (score 9):

> Given that `map()` is defined by `Enumerable`, how can `Hash#map` `yield` two variables to its block?

It doesn't. It `yield`s a *single* object to its block, which is a two-element array consisting of the key and the value.

It's just destructuring bind:

```
def without_destructuring(a, b) end
without_destructuring([1, 2])
# ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)

def with_destructuring((a, b)) end # Note the extra parentheses
with_destructuring([1, 2])

def with_nested_destructuring((a, (b, c))) p a; p b; p c end
with_nested_destructuring([1, [2, 3]])
# 1
# 2
# 3

# Note the similarity to
a, (b, c) = [1, [2, 3]]
```

Theoretically, you would have to call `map` like this:

```
hsh.map {|(k, v)| ... }
```

And, in fact, for `inject`, you actually *need* to do that:

```
hsh.inject {|acc, (k, v)| ... }
```

However, Ruby is more lenient with argument checking for blocks than it is for methods. In particular:

- If you `yield` more than one object, but the block only takes a single argument, all the objects are collected into an array.
- If you `yield` a single object, but the block takes multiple arguments, Ruby performs destructuring bind. (This is the case here.)
- If you `yield` more objects than the block takes arguments, the extra objects get ignored.
- If you the block takes more arguments than you are `yield`ing, the extra arguments are bound to `nil`.

Basically, the same semantics as parallel assignment.

In fact, before Ruby 1.9, block arguments actually *did have* assignment semantics. This allowed you to do crazy things like this:

```
class << (a = Object.new); attr_accessor :b end

def wtf; yield 1, 2 end

wtf {|@a, a.b| } # WTF? The block body is empty!

p @a
# 1
p a.b
# 2
```

This crazy stuff works (in 1.8 and older), because block argument passing is treated the same as assignment. IOW, even though the above block is empty and doesn't do *anything*, the fact that block arguments are passed as if they had been assigned, means that `@a` is set and the `a.b=` setter method is called. Crazy, huh? That's why it was removed in 1.9.

If you want to startle your co-workers, stop defining your setters like this:

```
attr_writer :foo
```

and instead define them like this:

```
define_method(:foo=) {|@foo|}
```

Just make sure someone else ends up maintaining it :-)

Comment: Very informative, I didn't even realize you could destructure in method params. I always figured they removed the paramaters as assignment because it meant you could accidentally clobber some var in the environment, and it wouldn't work the same between local vars and methods.