# In Ruby, why do certain methods return an error if unused block parameters aren't passed through (i.e: find)?

Tags: ruby

Given the following example:

```
hash = {1=>3, 4=>7, 3=>2, 5=>6}

hash.find{|k|k.odd?} #without value block variable will return an error
hash.find{|k,v|k.odd?} #returns [1,3]
```

Above we have two of the same examples, the only difference being one has a `value` block parameter passed in, whereas the other does not.

Even though the `value` block parameter is not used for the first example, it returns an error if it isn't included. Is there an explanation to why you must include certain block variables in order to satisfy certain Ruby methods, even though they aren't used? In this case, `value` was not used in the first example, but returned an error.

Comment: Note that `{ :a=>1, :b=>2 }.find{ |k| puts "k=#{k}" }` prints `k=[:a, 1]` then
`k=[:b, 2]`. This is because Katz decided there was no point in passing just a key or value to a block; that it only made sense to pass a key-value pair (as an array). Note that if we have `h = { :a=>1, :b=>2 }; h.find{ |k,v| ...}`, `k, v = h.each.next #=> [:a, 1]; k #=> :a; v #=> 1`

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of `Enumerable#find` is determined by the implementation of `#each`.

According to my documentation, `Hash#each` uses the C function `rb_hash_each_pair`.

```
# ruby/hash.c
static VALUE rb_hash_each_pair(VALUE hash)
{
    RETURN_SIZED_ENUMERATOR(hash, 0, 0, hash_enum_size);
    if (rb_block_arity() > 1)
        rb_hash_foreach(hash, each_pair_i_fast, 0);
    else
        rb_hash_foreach(hash, each_pair_i, 0);
    return hash;
}
```

When your block has an **arity** > 1 (e.g. you have two block variables) it **yields** two values.

```
# ruby/hash.c
static int each_pair_i_fast(VALUE key, VALUE value)
{
    rb_yield_values(2, key, value);
    return ST_CONTINUE;
}
```

When your block arity == 1 (when you have one block variable) it yields one value, an array.

```
# ruby/hash.c
static int each_pair_i(VALUE key, VALUE value)
{
    rb_yield(rb_assoc_new(key, value));
    return ST_CONTINUE;
}
```

If you are only interested in enumerating the keys, use `Hash#each_key`.

Comment: I asked a very similar question about `Hash#map` almost six years ago. You might find its answers interesting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550232/does-hash-override-enumerablemap

Comment: Jared, plus 1 for your hippocampus.